# how do I install hydrid worker extension in Azure after creating Hybridworker?

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I have created hybridworker with the code below

```
  $rgDRname = 'rgjt4061rbdr'
   $rgname = 'rgjt4061rb'
   $aaname = 'aajt4061rb'
   $hybridWorkerGroupName = 'hwrvmjt4061rbDNS1'
   $workerName= New-Guid


   $vmDNS1resource = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgDRname | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "vm*DNS1" }
   $vmDNS1resourceid = $vmDNS1resource.Id

   # Create a new Hybrid Worker configuration
   $hybridWorkerConfiguration = @{
       ResourceGroupName = $rgname
       AutomationAccountName = $aaname
       VmResourceId = $vmDNS1resourceid 
       HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName = $hybridWorkerGroupName
       Name = $workerName
   }

   # Add the new Hybrid Worker to the group
   New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker @hybridWorkerConfiguration
```

I am trying to install the Hybrid worker extension but unable to figure out easy way to get the registration url/ Settings part sorted.

```
$settings = @{
    RegistrationUrl = "https://your-automation-account.azure-automation.net/accounts/$automationAccountName"
}

Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -VMName $vmName -Location "YourVMRegion" `
    -ExtensionName $extensionName -Publisher $publisher -ExtensionType $extensionName `
    -TypeHandlerVersion $version -Settings $settings -ProtectedSettings $protectedSettings `
```

Please I need help with how to use the Set-AzVMExtension and also get the registration URl
-ForceRerun $true -Verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created hybrid worker using below script.

```c
# Your existing code to create Hybrid Worker
$rgDRname = '<RgDRName>'
$rgname = '<RgName>'
$aaname = '<AutomationName>'
$hybridWorkerGroupName = '<hybridWorkerGroupName>'
$workerName = New-Guid

# Provide the full resource ID of your VM
$vmResourceId = '/subscriptions/158bxxxxxxx48f/resourceGroups/XXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/XXXXX-vm'

# Create a new Hybrid Worker configuration
$hybridWorkerConfiguration = @{
    ResourceGroupName = $rgname
    AutomationAccountName = $aaname
    VmResourceId = $vmResourceId
    HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName = $hybridWorkerGroupName
    Name = $workerName
}

# Add the new Hybrid Worker to the group
New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker @hybridWorkerConfiguration
```

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/uxd9iAY.png)]

To install ***Hybrid worker extension***, you can make use of below modified script:

```c
$settings = @{
    "AutomationAccountURL"  = "https://1a0426bb-69xxxxxxx.jrds.eus.azure-automation.net/automationAccounts/1a0426bbxxxxxx";
};

Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName <VMResourceGroupName> -Location <VMLocation> -VMName <VMName> -Name "HybridWorkerExtension" -Publisher "Microsoft.Azure.Automation.HybridWorker" -ExtensionType HybridWorkerForWindows -TypeHandlerVersion 1.1 -Settings $settings -EnableAutomaticUpgrade $true
```

***Output***:

```c
RequestId IsSuccessStatusCode StatusCode ReasonPhrase
--------- ------------------- ---------- ------------
                         True         OK
```

To get **`AutomationAccountURL`** -> In your automation -> properties -> use Automation hybrid service url like below

[image]

when I confirm in portal, extension installed successfully like below:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

To get the **`automationHybridServiceUrl`**, you can make use of REST API like below:

Create an **Azure AD application** and grant API permission:

[image]

Generate the **access token**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://management.azure.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

**Use the below query to fetch the Automation Hybrid service URL:**

```json
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/Automationaccname?api-version=2021-06-22&$expand=properties($select=automationHybridServiceUrl)
```

[image]

***Output:***

```json
"state": "Ok",
"RegistrationUrl": "https://cdf826ae-f0a7-4fe3-b8a9-36f07XXXX.agentsvc.eus.azure-automation.net/accounts/cdf826ae-f0a7-4fe3-b8a9-36fXXX",
"encryption": {
"keySource": "Microsoft.Automation",
"identity": {
"userAssignedIdentity": null
}
},
"privateEndpointConnections": [],
"automationHybridServiceUrl": "https://cdf826ae-f0a7-fe3-b8a9-36f07XXXX.jrds.eus.azure-automation.net/automationAccounts/cdf826ae-f0a7-4fe3-b8a9-36f07XXX",
"RuntimeConfiguration": {
"powershell": {
"builtinModules": {
"Az": "8.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Is there a way to programmatically get the Automation Hybrid service URL without have to hard code?.

Comment: Okay. I was hoping maybe I could use Rest API calls. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, using Rest Api you can get URL please check the updated answer.